# Server Error 500 when downloading from AjaxFileUpload

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

There are many reports of this error but can't seem to make it go away.
I am making a simple webform project and trying to use the AjaxFileUpload.

When uploading a file I get an error.
In my ASPX page.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

and

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server"
        OnUploadComplete="UploadComplete" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,img,png,bmp" style="margin-top:25px;"/>
```

I have tried adding many elements to the config file most of witch I have included below. This is obviously condensed, not the whole file.

```
<add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" /><httpHandlers>
<add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
</httpHandlers>
<handlers>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler,AjaxControlToolkit" />
</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Not sure what I am missing here.
Thanks in advance,
Brandon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after changing browsers to Chrome I was able to see more of the error. It was for file type not allowed. Strange, but I defined the filetypes in my config file and it is working now.

```
  <configSections>
      <section name="ajaxControlToolkit" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxControlToolkitConfigSection, AjaxControlToolkit" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  
  <ajaxControlToolkit additionalUploadFileExtensions="jpg,bmp,png,img" />
```